# How to get the full path of an executable which is in $PATH in node.js?

Tags: node.js, operating-system

Is there a function in node.js to find an executable file which is located somewhere in the `$PATH`, similar to `which` builtin of Bash?

If not, I could always try to parse `process.env.PATH` and manually search in each directory, but I would rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might want to check out [which module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/which)

```
var which = require('which');
which('ls', function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);   // prints '/bin/ls' on mac 
});
```

Comment: For anyone wondering how to tell the full path specifically of Node from Node, use `process.execPath`.